How to check if a set of randomly generated data matches a given distribution?
I have a random number generator that should generate values based on a Beta 4,4 distribution and some minimum and maximum. (IE, values between 0.9 and 1.1)
I can generate a large set of numbers using it fairly quickly.
How can I check if the generator is behaving as expected? What statistical test could I run on the samples?
I can use tools such as Excel to calculate things like mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis, min, max, etc. I can also whip up scripts using C++ or Python to parse the data if an existing library would be useful here.

You could consider the chi-squared test for distributions. You might get a better response on cross-validated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

@fGDu94 Thanks, I'll post there as well. I was under the impression Chi-Squared did not work on non-integer data sets?

I think if you split your range of values it into distinct regions and could $(O)$ how many are in each region, and calculate $E$ the expected number of samples in that region (can be decimals), then do $\sum (O-E)^2/E$, I think this will work.
You could also try computing the empirical CDF and plot it against the CDF of your distribution. Computing moments may also help but doesn't prove anything

Usually Beta distributions produce values in $[0,1]$ unless you are also relocating and rescaling.  You may need a very large sample from your generator to be able to distinguish some other possibilities such as a truncated normal distribution with the same mean and variance.


Map your data $y_i$ to $[0,1]$ using transformation $x_i=\frac{x_i-0.9}{1.1-0.9}$.

Find the cdf of $\text{Beta}(4,4)$ as $F_X(x)=\int_{0}^x\,\frac{7!}{3!3!}t^3(1-t)^3\text{d}t$.

Find the empirical cdf of the transformed data $x_i$ ($n$ needs to be selected such that the empirical cdf remains almost unchanged, where the OP says it is possible to increase the sample size as much as we want).

Plot the cdfs obtained in steps 2 and 3 to visually compare them (you can also use P-P plot or Q-Q plot). Finally, you can use Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, which is based on the maximum distance of the two cdfs (see here for python implementation). As you are able to have a sufficiently large $n$, instead if using statistical tests, you can use one of other distance-like metrics for measuring dissimilarity of two probability measures (instead of $l_\infty$ distance used in the KS test) such as Kullback-Leibler divergence (see here), f-divergences, or the 1-Wasserstein metric (also known as earth-Mover's distance). The latter recently has become popular, which measures the area between the two cdfs (see here). If the random generator that you use works properly, the values of such distance-like metric need to be almost zero.


